# PHP date "last weekday" outputting the wrong month

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to get the `last weekday` of the current month using the code below.

I was expecting this to behave just like all of the other operators like `last friday of` and output the last weekday of this month. but instead its outputting the last weekday of the previous month.

I know that I can rectify this by using `modify( '+1 month' )` but why? Why is it the other operators like `last tuesday of` work fine but `last weekday` needs to be bosted by 1 month?

```
<?php
// outputs the previous months date
$gettoday = date( "Y-m-01" );
$freqdate = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'last weekday '.$gettoday ) );
echo 'next '.$freqdate;

//get the correct date
$gettoday = new DateTime( $gettoday );
$gettoday->modify( '+1 month' );
$gettoday = date_format( $gettoday, 'Y-m-01' );
$freqdate = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $gettoday . ' last weekday' ) );
echo 'next '.$freqdate;
?>
```

Comment: @CBroe I get it. You should post that as an answer mate as it answers my question on the subject.

Comment: Added an answer, added a bit about how you could approach this instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you had a wrong understanding of what “last” actually means here.

That has nothing to do with the last day or week of the month - it is “last” as in “the closest previous one”.

You can start with something like `strtotime('last day of 2020-03')` - that would give you `31 Mar 2020`, which is a Tuesday.

If you then *check* what day of the week this is, and it would be either a Saturday or a Sunday - *then* you can go `last friday` on that value again, to land on the latest week day of the month.

Edit:

Example for all months of 2020

```
for($i=1; $i<13; ++$i) {
  $year_month = '2020-'.$i;
  $last_of_month = strtotime('last day of '.$year_month);
  $weekday = date('N', $last_of_month);
  if($weekday < 6) {
    echo 'last weekday of ', $year_month, ' is ', date('Y-m-d, l', $last_of_month), "<br>\n";
  }
  else {
    $last_weekday_of_month = strtotime('last friday', $last_of_month);
    echo 'last day of ', $year_month, ' is ', date('Y-m-d, l', $last_of_month), ' - last weekday of ', $year_month, ' is ', date('Y-m-d, l', $last_weekday_of_month), "<br>\n";
  }
}
```

This will get you the following output:

```
last weekday of 2020-1 is 2020-01-31, Friday
last day of 2020-2 is 2020-02-29, Saturday - last weekday of 2020-2 is 2020-02-28, Friday
last weekday of 2020-3 is 2020-03-31, Tuesday
last weekday of 2020-4 is 2020-04-30, Thursday
last day of 2020-5 is 2020-05-31, Sunday - last weekday of 2020-5 is 2020-05-29, Friday
last weekday of 2020-6 is 2020-06-30, Tuesday
last weekday of 2020-7 is 2020-07-31, Friday
last weekday of 2020-8 is 2020-08-31, Monday
last weekday of 2020-9 is 2020-09-30, Wednesday
last day of 2020-10 is 2020-10-31, Saturday - last weekday of 2020-10 is 2020-10-30, Friday
last weekday of 2020-11 is 2020-11-30, Monday
last weekday of 2020-12 is 2020-12-31, Thursday
```

Comment: I'm not sure how last Friday would take me to the last weekday of a month. If the last weekday of the month wasn't a Friday it would be wrong. So I think just modifying it by plus one month then getting the last weekday is good enough and secure on its output.

Comment: You get the last day of the month, and you check if that was a Saturday or Sunday. If not - then you have found your last week day of the month already. If it is Sat or Sun - then you go `last friday` _from_ this last-day-of-month, to get the date of that friday, which _is_ the last weekday of the month then. Check the edit, I’ll add an example that explains the logic.